# Diagnosing heap fragmentation on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, c, macos, memory-management, heap-memory

A Core Foundation app I'm writing seems to be consuming way more memory (according to the "Real Mem" count in Activity Monitor) than I am ever actually allocating.

I have confirmed my actual allocations are what I expect them to be (about 10MB) via the Live Bytes Allocations view in Instruments, but the "Real Mem" count in Activity Monitor shows > 60MB and apparently growing. I've also confirmed there are no leaks, also using Instruments.

My application  keeps a large queue of buffers of varying size, and is constantly free()-ing and malloc()-ing buffers as it adds/removes queue items.

Having read a little bit about heap fragmentation, this seems a likely explanation for what is happening. So my questions are as follows:

1. **Is there any way to confirm this on OS X e.g. maybe get a visual representation of the heap?**
2. **Is there an optional low fragmentation heap manager for OS X as there is for Windows?**

For anyone who wants to replicate the problem, the following example code shows up the same symptoms quite nicely:

```
#define MAX_SIZE (10*1024*1024)

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

size_t actual_alloc=0;
size_t max_alloc=0;

char *bigbuf=NULL;
size_t bigsize=0;

for  (long x=0; x<10000000; x++)
{
    if (bigbuf!=NULL)
    {
        actual_alloc -= bigsize;
        free(bigbuf);
    }

    bigsize = rand() % MAX_SIZE; // alloc random amount up to MAX_SIZE
    bigbuf = (char*)malloc(bigsize);
    memset(bigbuf, 'x', bigsize);
    actual_alloc += bigsize;

    if (actual_alloc > max_alloc)
        max_alloc = actual_alloc;

    if (x%100==0)
    {
        printf("alloc = %u \t max = %u\n", 
             (unsigned long)actual_alloc, (unsigned long)max_alloc);

        // max_alloc tends towards 10MB, 
        //  "Real Mem" in activity monitor tends towards 60MB
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

If you remove the random element from the above code, you get around 10MB process memory usage as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The heap is a complicated data structure and what you're seeing is normal.  Just because you free() a buffer does not mean that the library is returning that memory to the OS.  System calls have a cost, so when the allocation system is asking for a chunk of memory it tends to ask for more than it needs so that subsequent allocations can return memory without going to the kernel.  The heap also likely maintains several allocation regions for different allocation sizes to avoid long searches and fragmentation.  By making allocations of random sizes, you've managed to initialize several of these buckets.

There is no way for you to anticipate the behavior of the memory allocation subsystem or other system libraries you link against, and therefore Activity Monitor or top or any other tool will not give you meaningful information.  If you want to track memory allocations or leaks, use a malloc debugger or a tool like valgrind.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question isn't clear, I know this is normal behaviour. What I want to know is (1) is there a tool to measure heap fragmentation, so I can prove my app is causing it, and (2) is there a low frag heap manager for OS X as there is for Windows.